# how to Block exception in code intercept until new Token in return from the server?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

this intercept will get a new token from the server if the token is invalid
how I will block the execution util the token is returned

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
   val originalRequest = chain.request
   var response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)

   if (response.code == AppConstants.TOKEN_IS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
      val newRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                          .header("Authorization", getTokenFromSharedPref())
                          .build()
      response = chain.proceed(newRequest)
   }

   return response
}

fun getToken(){

 CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val token = tokenEndpoint.getToken(
                    AppConstants().tokenBaseUrl,
                    requestMap
            )
            setTokenInSharedPref(context, token)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use runBlocking coroutine builder to lock a thread.  After that you can make requests in a cycle until token is returned.

Comment: how runblocking { response = chain.proceed(newRequest)} will make this a asyc